# SASS/Compass writing CSS in wrong dir, not listening to config.rb

Tags: ruby, sass, zurb-foundation, compass

I'm developing a Wordpress theme with SCSS, Compass, and Foundation. In my theme's root directory I have an "SCSS" folder with files that ultimately compile into a single style.css file in the parent folder.

I have a config.rb file that looks like this:

```
add_import_path "bower_components/foundation/scss"

http_path = "/"
css_dir = "/"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"

output_style = :nested
```

When I run this in the command line:

```
bundle exec compass watch
```

It works fine on my iMac (Ruby 2.0, Sass 3.4.12, Compass 1.0.3).

However...

My theme is actually located in a Dropbox folder that syncs across multiple devices. When I try to run the same command above on my Macbook (only difference is Ruby 2.2 vs 2.0 on iMac), the CSS file ends up being saved at a different location.

When I save my SCSS on my iMac, I see this in Terminal:

```
modified scss/style.scss
write style.css
```

When I save my SCSS on my Macbook, I get this:

```
Modified scss/style.scss
write /Users/nick/...long path.../scss/style.css
```

Any idea why it is doing this? Why is it using this absolute path? The config.rb file is the same on both machines since it's syncing via Dropbox. Is this a Ruby version issue?

Comment: Have you tried updating Ruby on your iMac to version 2.2 to see if that changes things?

Comment: I just tried, but it's not looking like an easy task. I tried installing via Homebrew, but it is giving me issues. It's not letting me "brew link libyaml" because I don't have access to /usr/local/src, I think because I am not the admin on this machine (it's a work computer).

Comment: There must be something about Ruby 2.2 that was causing this. I told RVM to use 2.0 as the default on my Macbook and it's working fine now.